# Django Bulk Zip upload

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to upload images to a gallery app. I want the user to be able to either load images normaly, or upload on zip file containing all the images for that gallery. Then it must be uncompressed and all images must be added to that model. This is for the admin site.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, get started and let us know when you get stuck. This question is far too broad to answer. What are you stuck doing? Working out how it fits together? Processing the zip files? Implementing this in the admin? Ask specific questions, and you'll get specific answers.

Comment: Which bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: Ok so far, the gallery app is done. You can add photos with the normal image upload field. I dont know how this fits together, when uploading a zip file, unzipping it, and then saving it to the model. The upload and unzip part i can do, just the actual images that have unziped, how do I save them to that model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use the existing django-app django-photologue which enables you to do that or have a look at how it is implemented there: https://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/source/browse/trunk/photologue/models.py.
If you see that photlogue is lacking some of the functionality you need, you could also subclass and extend photologue's models in your app!

Comment: thanks!just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925305/uploading-multiple-images-in-django-admin