# Uploading files using Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to upload .PDF files using the Django Admin interface and for those files to be reflected in a page on my website. Is this at all possible? If so, how do I do that? Otherwise, what could be a workaround for an admin user to privately upload files that will later be displayed in the site?

What I'm getting from the Django documentation on [File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/) is that the upload happens on the website itself, but I want to do this using the Admin interface so I know only an admin user can upload these files. Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467691/uploading-images-using-django-admin) question but this dealt with images. Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `FileField` I believe ...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Nothing special to do, django-admin has it already.

**models.py**

```
class Router(models.Model):
    specifications = models.FileField(upload_to='router_specifications')
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from my_app import models

admin.site.register(models.Router)
```

You'll see a file upload field in your model's admin now. If already a file for the model instance, you'll see a link to it as well.

When rendering a view to a user, pass the model(s) in the view's context and use the field's `url` property to link to the file.

```
<a href="{{ my_model_instance.specifications.url }}">Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! The backend db of this application is MS SQL, hosted on Azure. Do I change the value of the upload_to parameter to the name of the table or? I have the database open on Management Studio and I've added the tables accordingly but I still get errors. (Should this be an entirely different question or was it appropriate for me to ask this as a comment?)

Comment: Regardless of database used, files will not be stored IN the db, only a link to the file's location relative to the MEDIA_ROOT setting of your project. As such, it is probably good to go through some tutorials on static and media files in Django, there's a lot to learn but for good reason!

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!