# Django multiple image upload to S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, photo-gallery

I am struggling to find a solution for a photo gallery in django. I've checkout out every django photo package (photologue, imagekit, etc.) I could find an none of them are really helping me in my quest. 
I am trying to build a simple image gallery that will allow me to upload multiple photos from the django admin and store them directly in Amazon S3. Can someone please point me to a simple photo app capable of achieving this or what would be the simplest approach?

Thank you so much

Comment: [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is what you are looking for...

Comment: I will look into it, thank you. How can I set up multiple images upload in the admin with boto3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages) configured to use S3. After setting up django-storages with S3, you can simply use add the image field to your model:

`some_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')`

where `images` is the subkey/directory in the bucket specified in your setup.

The process is outlined [here](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) and [here](http://tech.marksblogg.com/file-uploads-amazon-s3-django.html).

In order to setup multi-image uploading, you can use:  [django-admin-multiupload](https://github.com/gkuhn1/django-admin-multiupload) or [django-photologue](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue) (built-in S3 support)
or see one of the similar questions:  [Uploading multiple images in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925305/uploading-multiple-images-in-django-admin)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the links. However that does not address the multiple image upload issue that I am facing. Is there something more standard already set up so I don't have to write everything from scratch? Cheers.

Comment: Please see the linked project `django-admin-multiupload` or one of the other stack overflow responses.  I am not sure what you're looking for...  You can easily setup the suggested package with django-storages to achieve multifile image uploads to S3 via the admin.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try test it out.